# Riak "w" is less than "n_val" clarification

Tags: riak

Consider Riak cluster with 5 nodes (A,B,C,D,E) in it, n_val = 3:

1) Coordinator node store (k,v) pair with w=2 that should go to node A and replicas should go to nodes B and C, according to consistent hashing.
Consider node C is down.  Riak is able to perform writes to two nodes - A and B, thus satisfying w=2. However, (k, v) should be eventually replicated to 3 nodes,
does this mean that Riak will send this store to D and D will perform hinted handoff when C is back? Or just writes to A and B would be performed and C will synchronize with these nodes using Active Anti-entropy and read repair?

2 Consider I would like to decommission node C from the cluster. I simply shutdown this node. This node contained data that is replicated on nodes D and E as well as replicas for nodes A and B. Now n_val = 3 is no longer satisifed, we only have two replicas. Will Riak automatically create new replicas for node that is down or should I execute special command to mark node C as permanently down?

3) Consider Riak cluster with 3 nodes (A, B, C), n_val=3 and node C is down. Will it be able to satisfy write with w=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Riak will make use of fallback vnodes, so in the event node C is down during the write, node D will start a fallback vnode to handle requests until it becomes available again.  As soon as C becomes available, D will intitiate hinted handoff to bring the vnodes on node C up to date.  The use of fallbacks is described [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/Replication/)

2) If you are removing node C while it is still able to function and wish to run a smaller cluster, use [cluster leave](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/cluster-admin/#leave) to  cause Riak to reassign ownership and transfer the data before shutting down node C.

If you are removing node C to replace it new hardware, first [join](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/cluster-admin/#join) then new node, but use [replace](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/cluster-admin/#replace) before plan or commit.

If node C has failed such that it's data is unrecoverable, you can use `force-remove` or `force-replace` to have new empty vnodes started to replace the lost ones, which will the be populated via AAE or read repair.

3) Yes, Riak uses sloppy quorums where a fallback vnode can be used to satisfy a read or write quorum.  If you want to only consider primary vnodes, use `pr` or `pw` in the request instead of `r` or `w`.  See [Eventual Consistency](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/Eventual-Consistency/) for more detail.